# How long does deployment of custom metadata from apex take in a production org

Tags: apex, mdapideploy

We are looking at using custom metadata type in a managed package. When in a scratch org deployment of custom metadata is speedy.

For those of you who have done this in production, does deployment of custom metadata types via apex using

```
Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment()
```

take as long as other deployment of changes sets etc?

We will have a user on a configuration page waiting and currently cannot store the job Id due to Mixed DML operation (I know there are ways around it) and then to check status would have to write code to check status via metadata api as well.

So curious if this type of operation is prioritized over others and it is quick or if it is the typical wait time for a given org.

Observations fro those who have done this would be great.

Comment: I use a MDT deployment to encrypt an Auth Secret after first use in a managed package and it works well.  I haven't timed it or tested against orgs with deployments pending, but it seems to move pretty quickly (i.e. takes less than a minute to finish)

Comment: What's the use case for the MDT?  Does it need to be performed quickly?

Comment: @BrianMiller - Saving configurations. Customers have a habit of clicking save then goto the app and check how it looks. Then call support if it looks like the settings did not take. Just looking to reduce support calls. I may just implement a polling process and not say it is saved until it actually is. Storing the job Id was meant to block the configuration page if a deployment is pending....I have seen deployments take over 24 hours in some orgs so also a bit concerned of the efficiency if this type is not prioritized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a matter of prioritization, it's a matter of database locks. When a metadata deployment occurs, it causes an [Org Lock](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321524&type=1&mode=1). Changes to Setup and certain features are uninterruptible operations. In most cases, this won't matter, because *most* orgs aren't actively installing/updating/etc things "right now" (i.e. all the time), but you should at least be aware that there *may* be a significant delay if the org is locked because of other subscriber interactions.

Comment: So there may be times when it takes hours....